# How to insert a line break after every dot in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In one of my web pages, I am retrieving the data from a back end SQL server database. 
That data sometimes contain multiple paragraphs without any line break.

I want that it should insert a line break automatically after every dots. 
How is it possible?

Anyone if knows the answer please help me here.

Comment: replace . with \r\rn

Comment: you should use regex skip numbers

Comment: Along with code you have so far you should post actual input and expected output. I am not clear if you mean that you want `br` tags added you are dealing with web content. What about numbers? Are there any other elements like `span` or tags that should be considered? See [mcve] for help on what you should provide.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
str = str.Replace(".", "." + Environment.Newline);
```

Comment: Perhaps a regex replace might be better suited. For example, some strings may contain ellipsis (`...`). The regex `\b\.` might do the trick.

Comment: @MikeEason - I believe that should be posted in a separate answer, instead of a comment

Comment: @Emre Tapci thank you for your time, using your logic i wrote the following which works fine, it can detect the dot and even it can replace it with any symbol if i want, but it does not insert a line break.        
                                                                                    
<p>@string.Format("{0}", @Model.description.Replace(".","."+Environment.NewLine))</p>

Comment: For HTML, you should replace Environment.Newline with <br>.

Comment: @EmreTapcı Thank you for replying back, I have already tried that, but this approach instead of inserting a line break, just simply prints out <br> as a value after each dot. I have also tried \n and \r\n but  unfortunately none of these approaches work. Do you have any other suggestion?